# Equicontinuous and bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\varepsilon \subset C^0$ is equicontinuous family of functions which is uniformly bounded.

I want to prove that $\{sup$ $f(x): f \in \varepsilon\}$ is a continuous 
function of $x$.

I can show the case where $\varepsilon$ is a countable set (by induction) but I don't how to show it for the uncountable case.

Comment: I don't know how you can show it for a countably infinite set by induction, because there is no infinite natural number.  You could show it for all finite sets by induction.

Comment: It is always true that a supremum of a collection of continuous functions is lower semicontinuous, so perhaps it will help to focus on showing that it is upper semicontinuous.